# Data: Attitude towards global warming

Tags: data-request, environmental-economics

I'm interested in data that reveals public opinion towards global warming in the US.

It'd be best to have a time dimension to it, but I'm interested in data from around the year 2000. Since it is quite a hot topic, I expect there to be much around this, but I couldn't find anything with *scientific standards* - say, anything beyond *political institution X / news channel Y  asked 1000 and we are not even sure what the phrasing of the question was*.

**I am especially interested in data that includes an indicator for income/wealth.**

Answer (score 3):

There's [this](http://www.pollingreport.com/enviro.htm) from Polling report showing raw survey data (question, sample data, and responses) back to 2012.

Additionally [this paper by Lorenzoni and Pidgeon](http://www.atmosp.physics.utoronto.ca/people/lev/ESSgc/lorenzoniPclimchng06.pdf) and [this paper by Leiserowitz](http://anthonyleiserowitz.com/pubs_assets/AmericanRiskPerceptions.pdf) (both 2005) discussing said data in a more academic context. You would need to do some substantial extrapolation to get time-series out of these though.

Answer (score 2):

I've done some more digging, and I'm adding this as a separate answer:

[This search of Roper Center data from UConn](http://www.ropercenter.uconn.edu/CFIDE/cf/action/catalog/catalogResult.cfm?keywordDisplay=climate%2520change&keyword=climate+AND++change&keywordOptions=1&organization=&fromDate=01%2F01%2F1935&toDate=&country=&type=&queryId=9115159&label=&studyId=&perPage=20&sortBy=BEG_DATE_DESC&filterDecade2010s=on) yielded a few interesting surveys. Namely, [this CBS survey from 2013](http://www.ropercenter.uconn.edu/CFIDE/cf/action/catalog/abstract.cfm?type=&start=&id=&archno=USCBS2013-03C&abstract=) and [this PRRI survey from 2011](http://www.ropercenter.uconn.edu/CFIDE/cf/action/catalog/abstract.cfm?type=&start=&id=&archno=USPRRI2011-09&abstract=). Both track income data and are rigorously documented. Lastly there was [this report entitled Americans on Climate Change from 2004](http://www.ropercenter.uconn.edu/CFIDE/cf/action/catalog/abstract.cfm?type=&start=&id=&archno=USUMARY2004-06&abstract=).

Digging even deeper, I found [this report from Pew from 2000](http://www.people-press.org/2000/07/13/june-2000-voter-attitudes-survey/) with a few questions on climate and a measure of income. I did not download the whole report though, and just perused the pdf, so your mileage may vary.

I did however just want to call both datasets out for being invaluable (much better than Gallup), so if there's more info you'd like, definitely peruse [The Pew Research Center for the People & the Press Poll Database](http://www.people-press.org/question-search/) or [the Roper Center Public Opinion Archives](http://www.ropercenter.uconn.edu/CFIDE/cf/action/catalog/index.cfm)